# Vertical center div with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I tried vertically centering a div with flexbox:
Oddly `align-items: center` didn't change anything. After playing around for some time I realized that I need to set body *and* html to `height:100%;`.

HTML:

```
<div id="login_container">
    <div class="login"></div>
    <div class="login"></div>
    <div class="login"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#login_container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height:100%;
}
.login {
    background-color: #008000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

For comparison: [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z8m6n6pz/) is working while [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/boyjembw/) isn't.

Why do I have to add

```
body,html {
    height:100%;
}
```

so that the div is vertically aligned? Am I missing something?

Comment: Or you could just use `100vh` https://jsfiddle.net/z8m6n6pz/1/

Comment: Why does the second not work? Because the height has to be 100% of *something* and you haven't told it what to be 100% of.

Comment: the HTML and BODY tags have `auto` height by default, meaning the height is based on the content. when you give them `height:100%` they will fill the entire height of the viewport. Alternatively, as suggested by @NenadVracar you can just use the viewport units instead. (be careful of browser support tho)

Comment: Open DevTools (F12) and inspect <html> element and it's height. Div #login_container is centered, it's just that the parent element height is too small for it to be seen.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. I missed that the body has no height unless there is some content. Sorry if this was a silly first question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default value of `height` is `auto`, this means your `html`/`body` will not be full screen.

To get full screen content you have specify height to `100%` or `100vh`.

> so that the div is vertically aligned? Am I missing something?

Yes, your content is vertically centred of parent (in this case vertically center to content of `html`/`body`). You have just missed to set height of `html`/`body` to `100%` (full screen).